# VB6: alternative to the HTML Object Library (for parsing HTML)

Tags: html, vb6, parsing

I've been using the HTML object library for a while for parsing HTML.

The library itself works perfectly, the only problem is that loading/initializing HTML using `createDocumentFromUrl` (even if it's a small file) takes way too long.

Does anyone know if there exists an alternative component?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a reference to **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5** then use regular expressions to parse it. The general recommendation is don't try to use regular expressions to parse html, but if you are looking for only a few tags this might work for you.